# How to represent a sentence with indirect object in RDF triples?

Tags: rdf

for example, this sentence:

> "I give John a book."

To make it as a set of triples:

```
I give John. 
John hasIndirect book.
book count 1.
```

or , it can be:

```
sentence1 subj I.
sentence1 pred give.
sentence1 obj   John.
sentence1 indObj book.
book   count   1.
```

So, is there already a set of RDF predicates defined in some namespace for this purpose?

Comment: It's difficult to answer a modelling question like this without knowing what you are trying to achieve, and why you are using RDF specifically...

Comment: I'd like to put some natural language sentences into RDF format,I don't want to invent my own predicates, so I wonder if there is something like vCard , dubline core for English sentence structure modelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this would normally be handled by reifying the event of the donation, e.g:

```
_:e1 a :GivingEvent;
     :recipient :john;
     :actor :me;
     :object [a dbpedia:Book; dc:title "foo"];
     :count 1.
```

which would also allow you to say when the giving took place, who else was there, etc.

> So, is there already a set of RDF
>   predicates defined in some namespace
>   for this purpose?

I don't know of one, sorry.